# Converse to natural proofs theorem?

Tags: circuit-complexity, lower-bounds, big-picture, p-vs-np, natural-proofs

Natural proofs paper shows 'if there is a natural property not possessed by any function in P/poly then there is no $2^{n^\epsilon}$-hard PRG'.

Is it easy to see the converse 'if *there is no $2^{n^\epsilon}$-hard PRG then there is a natural property not possessed by any function in P/poly*'.

The reason I seek is following. Even if SAT and $\#$SAT have $2^{O(2^{\sqrt{\log n}})}$ randomized algorithms then P is not NP is still possible. However in this case *there is no $2^{n^\epsilon}$-hard PRG* at any $\epsilon>0$. Then in this situation would it be possible to prove NP is not in P/poly by a natural proof?

Comment: So what you are asking is at least as strong as "if there is no exponentially hard PRG then NP is not in P/poly". This statement seems to imply an unconditional proof that NP is not in P/poly.

Comment: @SashoNikolov so does SAT and #SAT in randomized $2^{O(2^\sqrt{\log n})}$ imply no $2^{n^\epsilon}$ hard PRG at any $\epsilon>0$ which in turn imply NP is not in P/Poly? It could still be the case SAT and #SAT have deterministic linear time algorithm in which case NP is in P/poly.

Comment: @SashoNikolov I always thought SAT or #SAT in randomized $2^{O(2^\sqrt{\log n})}$ implies no $2^{n^\epsilon}$ PRG at any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question, because I definitely do not understand your response. I assume that by "natural property" you mean one that some NP problem has. You do not?

Comment: @SashoNikolov  I think there are two queries here (1) Does SAT/#SAT having $2^{O(2^{\sqrt{\log n}})}$ algorithm imply no $2^{n^\epsilon}$ hard PRG? (2) Does no $2^{n^\epsilon}$ hard PRG imply natural proof is possible? Note SAT/#SAT could still have an $O(n)$ algorithm meaning P=NP in which case no such PRG exists or SAT/#SAT needs $2^{\omega(\log n)}$ algorithm in which case such $2^{n^\epsilon}$ hard PRGs may exist. However $2^{O(2^{\sqrt{\log n}})}$ algorithm prohibits $2^{n^\epsilon}$ hard PRGs if **(1)** is true. On **(2)** I assume no $2^{n^\epsilon}$ PRG could still P vs NP open.

Comment: You did not answer my question. When you say "natural proof", natural proof of what statement?!

Comment: I think what he means is the usual sense of a natural property: roughly speaking it's a deterministic polytime algorithm that given a truth table distinguishes most "hard" functions from all functions in P/poly. The alg does not have to output "hard" on any NP function

Comment: @SashoNikolov I looked into the $90$s paper again. I am thinking similar to Williams' comment. It will esentially be a loop hole that makes functions not to be in P/poly.I am asking distinguishing P/poly particularly from NP. But isn;t that what the natural proofs paper tries to mark out?